# Join em 3 tabelas com firebird 2.5

Tags: sql, firebird

Bom dia! estou quebrando a cabeça para resolver um problema em meu primeiro aplicativo com firebird, o que estou tentando fazer é juntar dados selecionados de 3 tabelas.

```
SELECT T1.ID_CLIENTE, T1.NOME, T1.LIMITE, tb_cli_adicional.ADICIONAL1 AS DATA_CONSULDA_SPC, tb_cli_adicional.ADICIONAL2 AS OBS_CONSULTA, tb_conta_receber.VLR_CTAREC AS TOTAL_DEBITO
FROM TB_CLIENTE T1

LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID_CLIENTE, ADICIONAL1, ADICIONAL2 FROM tb_cli_adicional GROUP BY ID_CLIENTE) ON tb_cli_adicional.id_cliente = T1.ID_CLIENTE
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID_CLIENTE, SUM(tb_conta_receber.VLR_CTAREC) AS TOTAL_DEBITO FROM tb_conta_receber GROUP BY ID_CLIENTE) ON tb_conta_receber.id_cliente = T1.id_cliente
```

Ocorre o seguite erro: Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause).
Já tentei fazer pelo tópico seguinte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50130159/firebird-sql-join-tables
Também já tentei por o group by no final e não faz diferença.
Desde já peço desculpas pela burrice e agradeço qualquer ajuda que poderem dar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o erro está no seu primeiro `LEFT JOIN`, pois a quantidade de campos dos `select` deve ser a mesma que os campos a serem agregados, salvo os campos com as `functions` (SUM, MAX, MIN, etc.).

Seu código deve ficar assim:

```
SELECT 
    T1.ID_CLIENTE, 
    T1.NOME, 
    T1.LIMITE, 
    tb_cli_adicional.ADICIONAL1 AS DATA_CONSULDA_SPC, 
    tb_cli_adicional.ADICIONAL2 AS OBS_CONSULTA, 
    tb_conta_receber.VLR_CTAREC AS TOTAL_DEBITO
FROM TB_CLIENTE T1
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT 
                ID_CLIENTE, 
                ADICIONAL1, 
                ADICIONAL2 
            FROM tb_cli_adicional 
            GROUP BY ID_CLIENTE, ADICIONAL1, ADICIONAL2
        ) ON tb_cli_adicional.id_cliente = T1.ID_CLIENTE
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT 
                ID_CLIENTE, 
                SUM(tb_conta_receber.VLR_CTAREC) AS TOTAL_DEBITO 
            FROM tb_conta_receber 
            GROUP BY ID_CLIENTE
        ) ON tb_conta_receber.id_cliente = T1.id_cliente
```

Você pode dar uma olhada nesse link do site do FireBird sobre [Aggregations](https://www.firebirdsql.org/pdfmanual/html/nullguide-aggrfunc.html)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda